# Empty linear_layout with wrap_content glitch

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have empty LinearLayout with height set to wrap_content and it takes too much space. Should be padding or zero, but it takes around 80dp. Why? It is strange.

(same with any count of child inside, should takes space only to "cover" children, but takes more)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg"
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

I've found the reason. Background drawable expands LinearLayout. Ridiculous. How to fix this?

Comment: have you look at it with the preview tool?

Comment: post your whole layout code?

Comment: I've found the reason, now the question is how to prevent this background behavior..

Comment: @Gavriel: yes, the same

Comment: can you probe set paddings & margins to 0?

Comment: @gvsharma: not necessary, found the reason, but still need a fix

Comment: What is the desired outcome? I am guessing you want a 1dp or so height instead of wrapping nothing

Comment: @gilgil28 please read up post, there is a EDIT section.

Answer (score 0):

Make your background smaller. You might want to use 9 PNG to make the image stretch nicely within your layout.